# Cypress Assertion that a button does not exist

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, cypress, laravel-nova

How do I claim that a button does not exist? or is it not clickable?

For example in this case I say that something exists, if I wanted to assert that it does not exist?

```
cy.get('#nova > div > div.content > div.px-view.py-view.mx-auto > div.relative > div.card > div.relative > div.overflow-hidden.overflow-x-auto.relative > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) ').each(($e, index, $list) => {
            const text = $e.text()
                expect(text).to.eq('\n        Tommy\n      ')

        })
```

Comment: So you just want to assert that certain element does not exist?

Comment: exact yes @Jonah

Comment: Are there multiple buttons and you want to loop through them and check some button is not available ?

Comment: @AlapanDas yes exact

Comment: If your button is not available in dom then `each()` will not detect it.